# ERROR: Service 'mssql-init' failed to build : Build failed

Tags: training-certification

I am trying to follow steps in
Walkthrough: Using the **Getting Started template**  (sitecore 10 certification )

> Error when running powershell **.\up.ps1**
> Step 4/5: FROM ${PARENT_IMAGE}
> 10.2-ltsc2019: Pulling from sxp/sitecore-xp1-mssql-init
> 4612f6d0b889: Downloading [==================================================>]  791.4MB/791.4MB
> 5ee7a7ea9cf2: Download complete
> e422155dc57a: Download complete
> f90a98e468ea: Download complete
> bb82825bedcb: Download complete
> e2acafc2db71: Download complete
> b77008f646e6: Download complete
> efbb23e4c0ff: Download complete
> stream error: stream ID 41; HTTP_1_1_REQUIRED

**ERROR: Service 'mssql-init' failed to build: Build failed**

Comment: Did you find out what the issue was and how to resolve it?

Comment: If anyone coming across with this post then solution is run iisreset \stop  and try again it will work